# How to detect android mobile model in html5 app

Tags: android, html, mobile, mobile-application

I want to detect the model of the mobile, for example Samsung s6, moto g2 etc from the users who install my app. Is it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WURFL is your requirement is a complex one or you can use useragent (which is a property of webkit) to check the build manufactrurer. 
check below links for reference :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WURFL

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp